# on mouse move tooltip client x client y doesn't work in javascript function is there any similar to client x,y?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In plain JavaScript function for on mouse move tooltip should  move for the first time when I use the mouse move function using client x, y it works but when I repeat the function twice mouse move function is not working what might be the issue is that with client x, y?? , Please someone could answer this.

```js
const tooltip2 = document.querySelectorAll('.content-section-text + section');
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const x = (e.clientX + 5) + 'px',
    y = (e.clientY + 5) + 'px';
  for (var i = 0; i < tooltip2.length; i++) {
    tooltip2[i].style.top = y;
    tooltip2[i].style.left = x;
  }
};
```

```css
.content-section-text {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.content-section-text+section {
  display: none !important;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  color: #4D4E53;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 9px;
}

.content-section-text:hover+section {
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-content-section">
  <div class="content-section-icon">
    <img src="pic.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="content-section-text">N/A</div>
  <section class="tooltiptext1">Name</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Sorry about that .

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Though I'm wondering what will happen if there are say 10 tooltips on the page, your code will position all of the above each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version on more than one DIV

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches(".content-section-text")) return 
  const x = (e.x + 5) + 'px', y = (e.y + 5) + 'px';
  const tooltip2 = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  tooltip2.style.top = y;
  tooltip2.style.left = x;
});
```

```css
.content-section-text {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.content-section-text+section {
  display: none !important;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  color: #4D4E53;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 9px;
}

.content-section-text:hover+section {
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;
}
div.content-section-text { border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="left-content-section">
  <div class="content-section-icon">
    <img src="pic.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="content-section-text">N/A</div>
  <section class="tooltiptext1">Name</section>
</div>
<div class="left-content-section">
  <div class="content-section-icon">
    <img src="pic.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="content-section-text">N/A</div>
  <section class="tooltiptext1">Name</section>
</div>
<div class="left-content-section">
  <div class="content-section-icon">
    <img src="pic.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="content-section-text">N/A</div>
  <section class="tooltiptext1">Name</section>
</div>
</div>
```